# PHP add css class to element randomly using php

Tags: php, random, css-grid, gallery

let's say I have a array with e.g. 3 css class names - I also have a loop of e.g. 50 items and I'd like to randomly assign one of the three classes to an element - however, most of the items should not get any class at all - is there a way to do this?

to make it more clear - I'd like to set up a tiled gallery in Wordpress using css grid - every few picture I'd like to either add a class: big, wide, or tall - a gallery can have any number of pictures.
thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: We don't have a [mcve] here, so it is very hard for us to differentiate correct answers from incorrect answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_rand to get an item from an array where is stocked your class names

[php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: I'm aware of that but how do you only pick a class every so many items

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).